# Google Script E-mail Array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have the following Google Script. It runs through a spreadsheet and imports information into a Google Calendar. However, I also want it to populate an array with the uploaded data and send it in a Google email. Is this possible? Here is what I have so far.

```
var MAINTENANCE_EXPORTED = "MAINTENANCE_EXPORTED";
var MAINTENANCE_ERROR = "MAINTENANCE_ERROR";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [{name: "Upload CS Maintenance Schedule", functionName: "importCalendarCS"}, {name: "Upload EP Maintenance Schedule", functionName: "importCalendarEP"}];
  ss.addMenu("Maintenance Scripts", menuEntries);
}


//
//Coral Street Import Function
//
function importCalendarCS() {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('CS');
    var startcolumn = 1;  // First column of data to process
    var numcolumns = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of columns to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startcolumn, 1, numcolumns, 13)   // Fetch values for each column in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { // this is a "for loop" that asks the script to run through all rows.
    var column = data[i];
    var building = column[0];             // 1st column in spreadsheet "BLDG"
    var cart = column[1];                 // 2nd column in spreadsheet "CART OR LAB"
    var room = column[2];                 // 3rd column in spreadsheet "LOCATION OF CART OR ROOM"
    var deviceType = column[3];           // 4th column in spreadsheet "TYPE OF DEVICES"
    var deviceQuantity = column[4];       // 5th column in spreadsheet "# of Devices"
    var maintenancePerson = column[5];  // 7th column in spreadsheet "Maintenance Person"
    var maintenanceDate = column[6];      // 6th column in spreadsheet "Maint Date"
    var maintenanceImported = column[13];
    var title = building + " - " + room;
    var description = "Building: " + building
    + "\n" + "Room: " + room
    + "\n" + "Cart: " + cart
    + "\n" + "Device Type: " + deviceType
    + "\n" + "Device Quantity: " + deviceQuantity;
    var calendarName = "Cart Maint Schedule";

    if (maintenancePerson == "Bobby Obvious") {
      var email = "example@example.com"
      }
    else {
      var email = "example@example.com"
      }



    if ((maintenanceImported  != MAINTENANCE_EXPORTED) && (maintenanceImported != MAINTENANCE_ERROR) && (building != "BLDG") && (cart != "Cycle 1 Checklist") && (cart != "Cycle 2 Checklist")) {  // Prevents importing duplicates
      var cal = CalendarApp.openByName(calendarName);
      var advancedArgs = {description: description, location: ("Cart: " + cart)};
      var itsEmail = "example@example.com";

      if

      if (maintenanceDate != "") {
        cal.createAllDayEvent(title, new Date(maintenanceDate), advancedArgs);
        var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('CS');
        sheet.getRange(startcolumn + i, 14).setValue(MAINTENANCE_EXPORTED);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
      }
      else {
        var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('CS');
        sheet.getRange(startcolumn + i, 14).setValue(MAINTENANCE_ERROR);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.  Use the `MailApp` class.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

or the `GmailApp` Class:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `MailApp.sendEmail` method. It accepts an address.